# In C++, can you avoid repeating the same list of input parameters in a child class?

Tags: c++

Let's say I have a parent class that takes a list of params, including a `MyClass` object. And I have child class that takes the same list, except the child needs to take in `MyClass2` object instead of `MyClass`, and the child classes may also have different behavior for some overridden functions.

Is 'hiding' the  `MyClass` field with `MyClass2` in child class the right way to achieve this, as below?

Note `MyClass` or `MyClass2` is NOT in the param list, it's just defined in the field list.

```
class Parent {
   public:
     Parent(std::string a, std::string b, int x, int y ) _a(a), _b(b), myObj_(myObj), x_(x), y_(y) { // blah blah };

     virtual void doSomething(){
         //do something with myObj
     }

  protected:      
    std::string _a;
    std::string _b;  
    MyClass myObj_;   
    int x_;
    int y_;       
};
```

and I have a child class that inherits from Parent, and overrides `MyClass` with `MyClass2` and everything else remains the same.

```
class Child : public Parent {
   public:
     Child(std::string a, std::string b, int x, int y ): Parent(a,b,x,y) { }; //inherits parent's constructor

   void doSomething(){
         //do something DIFFERENT with myObj2
   }

  protected:       
    MyClass2 myObj_;  // overrides (hides?) the `MyClass` in `Parent`       
};
```

Comment: Are you certain that you want your `Child` class to contain identically-named copies of the members it already inherits from `Parent`?

Comment: `Child` should not try to redefine `_a`, `_b`, `x_`, and `y_`. A derived class has all members of all of its base classes, then can have *additional* members, you cannot override members

Comment: `MyClass2 myObj_;` doesn't override anything, the derived class contains both variables. The parent one can still be accessed as `Parent::myObj_`. You need to fix your design first, before thinking about a convenient constructor syntax.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat so what is the proper way to do member field overriding in c++ like i do in python or java ? Or is this appropriate pattern ?

Comment: It's not possible to have the inheritance if you don't want one of the parent's members. Perhaps create a class template, with `MyClass`/`MyClass2` as a template parameter. You can either implement everything directly in the template, or inherit stuff that doesn't depend on the template parameter from a non-template base class.

Comment: If you think you can override a field in Java, then you are gravely mistaken.

Comment: This fails the substitution principle (LSP).  It is probable that inheritance is not the right relationship here.

Comment: I think in your case, Parent should be abstract and should not hold myObj_ at all.  doSomething should be pure-virtual, and whatever logic you wanted in the base class should be moved into a derived class.  Then you have Child1 with MyClass, and Child2 with MyClass2, etc.  Both override doSomething, and do the right thing with their own data.

Comment: If all your `Child` constructor does is call the `Parent`s constructor, you can declare it as `using Parent::Parent`.

Comment: I think the correct term to be used instead of "hide" is "shadow". AFAIK yes, it shadows the parent's variable. but yet it can still be accessed by explicitly stating the namespace.

Comment: +1 to @Super-intelligentShade's comment this is my preferred way but just wanted to add an alternative: variadic template and std::forward.

Comment: @Super-intelligentShade how do you do it ?

Answer (score 1):

If the parameter list of the `Child` constructor is exactly the same as `Parent`, you can declare [inherited constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration#Inheriting_constructors) like this:

```cpp
class Parent
{
public:
    Parent(std::string a, std::string b, int x, int y);
    ...
};

class Child : public Parent
{
public:
    using Parent::Parent; // inherits Parent(std::string...)
    ...
}
```

Now you can do this:

```cpp
Child c{"Hello", "world", 42, 69};
```

Comment: I didn't fully understand what you are trying to do with `MyClass` and `MyClass2`, but what you laid out in your question seems OK.

Answer (score 1):

Super-intelligent Shade has a possible solution, but the drawback is that you cannot customize the child's constructor this way. You can use perfect forwarding as an alternative:

```
class Child: public Parent
{
    template<typename... Args>
    Child(Args&&... args): Parent(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {
        /* Do child-related things here */
    }
    ...
};
```